# addApi(Games.API) is deprecated

Tags: android, google-play-games

I have this code:

```
apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(Games.API)
        .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
        .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not connect to Play games services");
                finish();
            }
        }).build();
```

It says at the second line that "API" is deprecated but it doesn't give me something to use instead.

If I remove it, I get

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: must call addApi() to add at least one API

Comment: "no longer necessary to provide"... So, just remove it? https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Games.html#API

Comment: If I remove it then all the app crash...

Comment: With what exception? Have you seen sample code here? https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/ButtonClicker/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/bc/MainActivity.java#L141

Comment: how'd you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This entire method of accessing Google APIs [is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-api-client) so it may be that those methods have all been deprecated to prompt developers to switch to the newer access method ([1](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client), [2](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApi)).

The long term solution is to replace your current code with [code based on `GamesClient`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Games).